# Mock an import from another file but still return a mock value

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, jestjs

I'm testing a function which calls another function imported from `anotherFile`. That `outsideFunc` returns an object which contains 'name'. I need this to exist in order to progress through the rest of my test/the function to work correctly.

**systemUnderTest.js**

```
import { outsideFunc } from './anotherFile.js';

function myFunc() {
   const name = outsideFunc().name;
}
```

**anotherFile.js:**

```
export function outsideFunc() {
   return { name : bob }
}
```

I don't care about testing `anotherFile` or the result of `outsideFunc`, but I still need to return a mock value as part of testing `myFunc`;

**systemUnderTest.spec.js**

```
describe("A situation", () => {
  jest.mock("./anotherFile", () => ({
    outsideFunc: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
      name: 'alice'
    })
  }));

  it("Should continue through the function steps with no problems", () => {
    expect(excludeCurrentProduct(initialState)).toBe('whatever Im testing');
  });
});
```

The problem I get is that, when the unit test is working through `myFunc`, `const name` returns `undefined` where it should return `alice`. I would expect it to get the data from my `jest.mock` of the `anotherFile` file and its mock exported function, but it doesn't get the right response.

When I asset that I expect `name = alice` I actually get `name = undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**systemUnderTest.js**

```
import { outsideFunc } from './anotherFile.js';

// let's say that the function is exported
export function myFunc() {
   const name = outsideFunc().name;
   // and let's say that the function returns the name
   return name;
}
```

you can describe in your

**systemUnderTest.spec.js**

```
import { myFunc } from './systemUnderTest';
import { outsideFunc } from './anotherFile';

// using auto-mocking has multiple advantages
// for example if the outsideFunc is deleted the test will fail
jest.mock('./anotherFile');


describe('myFunc', () => {
  describe('if outsideFunc returns lemons', () => {
    outsideFunc.mockReturnValue({name: 'lemons'});
    it('should return lemons as well', () => {
      expect(myFunc()).toEqual('lemons');
    });
  });
});
```

[working example](https://repl.it/repls/GleefulLightblueVolume)